# Why are reference handles defined in C++/CLI instead of a "pointer overload"?

Tags: c++-cli

I'm working through some C++/CLI at the moment and am curious as to why there are reference handles instead of "overloaded pointers".  By "overloaded pointers", I mean the use of the * pointer notation that the Visual C++ 2010 compiler infers being different from C++ pointers.

For example, in the standard main header:

```
int main(array<System::String ^>^ args)
```

I am aware of the reason for the ^ trailing the right angle bracket, as outlined on MSDN.

I am aware that String is a .NET object type and is thus a reference, but I am used to Objective-C where references to objects take the standard pointer notation:

```
NSString * string = ... etc.
```

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: I don't follow, Microsoft should change the syntax of the language because you are used to Objective-C?  Does that strike you as a reasonable request?

Comment: @Hans: lol... the way you mention it, it sounds a little more unreasonable than it actually is. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because technically, references and pointers are different. References are opaque pointers, managed by the runtime; pointers are unverifiable and managed by the programmer. Using the same syntax for both would probably have been possible but could have produced a lot of confusion and potential bugs.

Comment: Not "could have", but **did**.  It was tried in the failed experiment called "Managed Extensions for C++" (the C++.NET version introduced in VS2002, which was such a disaster it was quickly replaced by C++/CLI)

Comment: Also, only pointer arithmetic is unverifiable.  Using a pointer doesn't have to be.

Comment: @Mehrdad, @Ben - thanks for your comments guys!  This clears up the rationale for me considerably.

Comment: @Ben: I did not know that... I never used the Managed Extensions (never really knew much about them either). Interesting to know, thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad - yeah, the managed extensions/CLI stuff is kind of exotic, eh ?  I am more interested in native Windows C++, but the book I am reading has both and my curiosity had to be satisfied.

Comment: @Ben, Medrdad - Just realized the difference between native C++ heap (pointers), and .NET managed heap (handles).

Comment: @Scott: No.  Handles are only to managed objects in the garbage collected heap.  But pointers can be to stack variables, native allocated variables, or pinned managed objects.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Pointer arithmetic could be largely verifiable if the so-called "pointer" type were a combination of an object reference and an offset.  Actually, I'd really like to see architectures which could work efficiently with such a type, since I would expect it could improve a number of multiprocessing scenarios.  Full memory barriers are becoming increasingly expensive; 'pointers' which contained information about the object containing them could allow for more precise ordering semantics.

Comment: @supercat: You need to do more than just guarantee that pointer arithmetic doesn't move outside the object, you need to guarantee that it doesn't overlap with any field(s) of incompatible type.  What it really boils down to is an array reference and index, and yes that supports arithmetic and is verifiable, only it's a little overly restrictive, type-wise, since manipulating an array of longs as a sequence of bytes would be perfectly safe.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: One does need to go somewhat beyond to provide total protection against everything that can go wrong, but one can make things pretty secure without too much complexity.  Probably the most notable requirement would be to have multiple forms for each reference: an 'transparent' form which allows direct indexing, and an 'opaque' form which does not; only classes that are allowed to manipulate the innards of classes would be allowed to create the transparent form from an opaque one.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: BTW, being able to have a few ways of expressing each object reference could offer some other advantages.  One I'd really like to see would be a zero-overhead kinda-sorta-weak reference (using a bit in the reference itself).  If the only references to an object are, or are via, KSW references, that would cause an object to be marked kinda-sorta-live, and could optionally trigger a notification routine (like a finalizer).  The essential idea behind KSW references is that the entities holding them would be using them to maintain data on behalf of other entities. ...

Comment: @Ben Voigt: KSW references would be superior to weak references in that (1) they would have less overhead, and (2) their targets could be accessed without creating strong references.  I wonder if any framework has such a thing?  Do you like the concept?

Comment: @supercat: I can't tell the difference between that and the WeakReference class .NET already has.  References are never zero-overhead, since the garbage collector has to update them when the object gets promoted to a different generation, and in order to trigger a notification, you'd need reference counting, which is also not zero overhead.  But we're getting off-topic now.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: A weak reference can only be dereferenced by turning it into a strong reference.  The idea of a KSW reference is that it could be used as a KSW reference.  If a "change counter" object is hooked to another object's "change" event, even if one uses weak events, a strong reference to the "counter" object would be created every time the object changes.  While the counter would sometimes be eligible for GC, it might not be eligible when GC occurs.  Using KSW references, the "change counter" object could find out when nobody cares about it anymore and unsubscribe.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Anyway, returning to the earlier discussion, I've often wished that .net would support "array reference" as a function/property return type, so that properties could be used as lvalues.  Such a thing would be a bit like a pointer, but without the dangerous implications thereof.

Comment: @supercat: You might like `ArraySegment`.  The syntax could be nicer though.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Does ArraySegment have any special features to make it behave like a lvalue?  Basically, what I'd like to see would be a means by which e.g. a Dictionary<Integer, Point> could be accessed the same was an an Array<Point>.  The indexing operator of an array returns an lvalue, so one can do, e.g., "MyArray[3].X = 5;" or "Interlocked.Increment(MyArray[3].X);".  What I'd like would be for other types to be able to return lvalue properties, allowing e.g. "Interlocked.Increment(MyDict[3].X);"  I'm not sure what one can do with an ArraySegment, since it doesn't even have a default indexer.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: BTW, another way to create a 'pointer-ish' thing within a 'safe' context would be to have a property whose "logical" type is, e.g. Point, method which accepts a delegate with a reference parameter of that type and calls it upon the thing to which the property should refer.  That wouldn't be quite enough to do everything a real lvalue could do (that would require variadic delegates) but would allow non-arrays to be behave more like arrays in many contexts (if the compilers could rewrite code in a fashion conceptually similar to the rewrites for iterators and closures).

Comment: @supercat: That's a good example that you should also describe for Eric at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/23/ref-returns-and-ref-locals.aspx since he's thinking about adding lvalue return types to C# (and if they go into C#, they'd get added to the BCL).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Interesting.  I just posted a couple comments there.  I suggested that it should only be permissible to return references to heap-derived objects, and further suggested that it may be useful to have a parameter qualifier "heap ref" which would only allow heap-derived objects to be passed in; parameters so declared might perhaps be returnable by reference, or usable in closures.

Comment: @Ben, @supercat: How would ambiguities be resolved, though? If you have a property with a setter which also returns an l-value, what happens if you assign to it?

Comment: @Mehrdad: What happens if you try to write two setters now?  The compiler resolves them based on the parameter types, and errors if they're ambiguous.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'd probably write the rules to require that operations be unambiguous (so if has an interface with a read-only foo, an interface with a write-only foo, and one wants an interface which inherits both of those but provides a by-reference foo, the by-reference version must explicitly shadow the read-only and write-only versions).  I would, however, also provide that in the absence of an explicit implementation of a read-only, write-only, or read-write property, the system could substitute a read-write or reference property.  I would further provide that...

Comment: @Mehrdad: ... the combination of a read-only property in one interface and an identically-named write-only property in another could be disambiguated based upon whether the property was being read or written.

Comment: @Ben: You can have multiple setters for a property?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, but only if they have different arguments (C# calls them *indexers*).

Comment: @Ben: Er... I know what indexers are, but those aren't the *same* property with different setters. They're indexed with different types, so they're different properties, just overloading each other. (A correct example would be if the indexed type was the same, but the value type was different.) While the CLR *does* allow multiple setters -- and even getters -- for a single property, C# doesn't.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The properties overload each other/the setters overload each other... the effect is the same.

Comment: @Ben: ... what? You can't even *have* the latter in C#, so there's no "effect" to talk about in the first place...

Comment: @Ben: BTW, on some further consideration I don't like the idea of being able to pass references to closures unless whoever created the references was expecting them to be so passed.

Comment: @supercat: Since you can already create a closure out of the class object, and then access the member from inside the closure, I don't see what the problem would be.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: The issue is that in the absence of closures, the way I'd expose a property by reference, the entity exposing the property would know when the recipient was "done" with it, very well fitting the model of "check-out/modify/check-in".  If a property were checked out and then put into a C# closure, there would be no way to check it in.  Actually, if I had my druthers there would be a distinction between "up-stack" closures (which persist variables) and "down-stack" closures (which cannot themselves persist outside the current stack frame)...

Comment: @Ben Voigt: ...but at present .net makes no distinction.  Actually, the distinction would be a good one for a variety of reasons I would think, since the same issues of wanting to know when outstanding references exist to something would exist with reference types and closures as would exist with exposing value-type properties by reference.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben Voigt: In what circumstance can the system resolve setters based on type?  Personally, I see no reason it shouldn't be able to (IMHO, it should be permissible to have a property "foo" with a getter of type Complex, a setter of type "Double", and another setter of type "Complex"; certainly one could have multiple overrides of a setter method, but I know of no such feature for properties).

Comment: Properties with arguments are called *indexed properties* or *indexers*; overloading based on index arguments is possible but not based on the assigned type (at least not directly, with a helper type and implicit conversions it is possible).  The situation would be the same for a reference-returning property since the return type does not participate in overloading.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: (I meant to have that as a comment--oh well) I would consider different combinations of indexer arguments to be different properties.  To my mind, an ability to resolve setters based on type would imply that the system could select among setters based upon the type of value to be set; there are a number of scenarios where that could be useful (or for that matter, even in a single-setter case, where it may be useful to have a setter accept a type which is different from, but has a widening conversion from, that of the setter).